# Updating mysql DB with form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

What is wrong with this code? I tried it several times but my DB is not updating after submitting.. I have a table with in the last column check-boxes. The check-boxes show correctly the value from the DB, but I also want the option to update the DB with the check-boxes. So if the value is 1 then the check-box is checked, but I want to be able to uncheck it (or check another that's unchecked) and click on the submit button below to change the value in the DB.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registered ORDER BY datum"   ; 
$myData=mysql_query($sql) ;
?>

<table width="1100" border="1">
<tr>
    <th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px"><b>naam</th>
    <th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">betaald?</b></th>
</tr>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $betaald = $_POST['betaald'];

    mysql_query($con,"UPDATE registered SET betaald='$betaald'");

    header("Location: index.php");

} ?>


<?php

    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
    {
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo  $record['naam'] ?></td>
           <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"> 
            <td> <input type='checkbox' name='betaald' id='betaald' value='1' <?php echo ($record['betaald']==1 ? 'checked' : '')?>> </td>

        </tr>

<?php

    }

    mysql_close($con);

?>


</table></p>

<input style="border:1px solid black" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save changes">

</form>
```

Comment: How many records do you have in db? What is `primary key` is in db?

Comment: for one thing, ID's are supposed to unique and someone even said that in your other question.

Comment: then this line's wrong `mysql_query($con,"UPDATE registered SET betaald='$betaald'");`

Comment: In before "You should use MySQLi instead of MySQL" ;)

Comment: Thank you. I got one step closer: now everytime I press the sumbit button, it gives all the rows value '1', so every checkbox is checked. On sumbit it just gives every row the value '1'. It doesn't matter what I check or uncheck, it always gives all the rows the same value

Answer (score 0):

You passed wrong parameters to `mysql_query()`.

The syntax is `mysql_query($query);` The second parameter is optional

Remove `$con` from the function.

Comment: Then do one thing.Commend the header() function and print your update query.

Comment: I got one step close: now everytime I press the sumbit button, it gives all the rows value '1', so every checkbox is checked. On sumbit it just gives every row the value '1'. It doesn't matter what I check or uncheck, it always gives all the rows the same value

Comment: Your update query was worked and updated all the rows. That is the reason for all the values are same in your concept. Add where clause in your query with primary / unique key to update a specific record

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual of php.net , the first param is query ,and the second is link identifier(as your $con) which is optional

`mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`

Comment: you may add db name before table name , such as `registered`  to  `db_name.registered` . If it not help, you may try echo mysql_errno() AND mysql_error() after query